# How can I display the remaining data on the last page of pagination?

Tags: node.js, angular

So my paginator works, but for some reason, my last page isn't displaying the remaining data, instead I think what is happening is that it's displaying the last full page of data, and not the remainder. For instance, if I have 111 documents and I display 25 at a time, I would expect there to be 5 pages worth of data, with the last page having 11 documents on it instead of 25. Right now the last is the 5th page, but it displays 25 documents.

This is my paginator in the HTML:

```
<mat-paginator class="paginator"
              [length]="numberOfGames"
              [pageSize]="10"
              [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25]"
              (page)="getGameInfo($event)"
              >
</mat-paginator>
```

This is my TS file in angular:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getGameInfo(null);
  }

  getGameInfo(event?: PageEvent){
    this.games.getAllGames(event).then((data: any) => {
      console.log(data);
      this.numberOfGames = data.numberOfGames;
      this.gamesArray = data['games'];
      this.assignGames();
      this.loading = false;
    })
  }
```

This is my service:

```
getAllGames(data: any) {
    return this.http.post(this.url + `api/games`, data).toPromise();
  }
```

This is my node route:

```
Game.find().then(games => {
        console.log(req.body)
        const items = games;
        const page = parseInt(req.body.pageIndex) || 1;
        const pageSize = parseInt(req.body.pageSize) || 10;
        const pager = paginate(items.length, page, pageSize);
        console.log(pager.endIndex)
        const pagedGames = items.slice(pager.startIndex, pager.endIndex + 1);

        pagedGames.forEach(game => {
          const matchTime = moment.utc(game.matchTime, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm')
          const localTime = matchTime.local().format('LLL');
          game.matchTime = localTime;
        })
        
        return res.status(200).json({
          message: 'Games fetched successfully',
          pager,
          games: pagedGames,
          numberOfGames: items.length
        });
```

Comment: I'm afraid this description is far too vague for the fairly complex problem that may potentially have a crazy amount of reasons. For starters, look at the requests generated in your browser. Is it that at some point you send a wrong request? Or do you get a wrong response for the valid request? Or is the whole communication as you expected it to be for each and every page, but the data is presented in a wrong way? Check the requests and the responses and that will tell you whether the problem is in the frontend or the backend

Comment: @KamilJanowski so I'm getting all the data back, it's just that there should be one extra page at the end, with like 11 more things on it, but there isn't because the pagination doesn't have that last page.

Comment: right... but what does it really mean that you don't have the last page? Pagination can be solved in a million different ways both in the backend and the UI. Do you have the page links at the bottom and the link for the 5th 11-element page is not displayed? Do you have the link to the 5th page, but the server doesn't return anything when you request its content? Do you have infinite scroll kind of paging and the content of the 5th page is never requested? Or is the content of the 5th page never returned despite the fact that you send a valid request for it?